# [Shopify]How can I change the list order on search result?

Tags: shopify

I want to customize the search result in product->article->page order.

How can I do that? I have tried some ways but it always showed page first.

I am using Debut theme.

Here is my current code in search.liquid

```
    {% for item in search.results %}
{% if item.object_type == 'product'%}
<li class="list-view-item">
{% include 'product-card-list', product: item %}
{% else %}

<div class="product-card product-card--list">
<a href="{{ item.url }}" class="full-width-link">
<span class="visually-hidden">{{ item.title }}</span>
</a>

<div class="list-view-item__link">
<div class="list-view-item__image-column">
<div class="list-view-item__image-wrapper product-card__image-wrapper">
{% unless item.image == null %}
<img class="list-view-item__image" src="{{ item.image.src | img_url: '600x600' }}" alt="{{ item.image.alt | escape }}">
{% endunless %}
</div>
</div>

<div class="list-view-item__title-column">
<div class="list-view-item__title" aria-hidden="true">
<span class="product-card__title">{{ item.title }}</span>
</div>
<div>
{% if item.published_at %}{{ item.published_at | date: format: "date" }} &#8212; {% endif %}
{{ item.content | strip_html | truncate: 200 }}
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
{% endif %}
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

If anyone can help would be great, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a `sort` pipe operator? https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/sort/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried. But there are 3 different types of data on the page. The sort function could not work.